# How to prevent text-shadow from overlapping text on previous line

Tags: html, typography, css

Is it possible to prevent `text-shadow` from overlapping text within the same element (e.g. a `h1`)? Please see an exaggerated example image below – in my use case I would like the text to be very bright white, but instead the shadow is overlapping it and causing murky grey areas.

[image: Example of nasty text-shadow overlap]

I made a reduced test case here to demonstrate: http://codepen.io/approach/pen/LgaIe

Note : I deliberately used a small `line-height` to highlight this issue

Comment: I should add, i deliberately used a small `line-height` to highlight the issue!

Comment: looks like a bug. It doesn't overlap if you set it downwards.

Comment: Only posibility I see, duplicate the element, set the duplicated element with transparent font, shadow set, and a lower z-index.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider putting another layer of text above the shadowed text:

**[Basic Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/2Vtv4/2/)**

```
<div class="cover">
     <h1><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit eveniet eos deleniti provident ab nam laborum at voluptatem est iste ratione quis error perspiciatis debitis.</a></h1>

</div>

.cover{
 position:absolute; 
 top:0;
}
.cover h1 a{
 color: white;
}
```

Or to save a little time and typing:

**[jQuery Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/2Vtv4/1/)**

```
$(function () {
    $('.wrapper').children().clone().css({
        position: 'absolute'
    }).prependTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a pseudo element.

http://codepen.io/andrewtibbetts/pen/OXzvOd

First, get the content repeated into an attribute on the element:

```
<div class="text-shadow" data-content="This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow.">This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow. This text has a shadow.</div>
```

Next, the css:

```
.text-shadow {
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 -.5em 1em black;
    color: transparent;

    &:after {
        content: attr(data-content);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this Works great!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't.

Try to use a smaller shadow or make the text `line-height` larger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See my comment under the original question above -- forgot to mention the `line-height`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
h1 { 
   text-shadow: 0 0 2px white, 0 0 10px grey, 0 0 4px black; 
}
```

you can have unlimited number of text shadows. so by putting a white one first, it may help clear out the grey /black. Adjust the pixels and such, to get it working how you want.

Comment: Thanks. In theory it sounds like it should work. I'll experiment and report back.

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to make your `line-height` bigger, say `line-height: 1.3em;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See my comment under the original question above -- forgot to mention the `line-height`.